# ProxyPass, ProxyReverse vs AJP

Tags: apache, tomcat, ajp, proxypass

I currently have a Tomcat + Apache HTTP server setting to serve my Java servlet:

```
ProxyPass /myservice http://localhost:8080/myservice
ProxyPassRerverse /myservice http://localhost:8080/myservice
```

This is all fine except that `myservice` needs to know the client IP address, which always turns out to be 127.0.0.1 due to the proxy. Is there a solution to get the real IP address? Is AJP an option?

```
doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    request.getRemoteAddr()
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Do it like this:

in the apache config:

```
<Location /foo>
  ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/foo
  ProxyPassReverse ajp://localhost:8009/foo
</Location>
```

And then in your server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8009" 
           enableLookups="false" secure="true" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           tomcatAuthentication="false"
           protocol="AJP/1.3" />
```

That should pass everything through.  The AJP protocol passes the info, but http: doesn't.

You may not want secure="true", I use that because SSL is handled at the apache layer and I need tomcat to know that the connection should be considered a secure one.

Comment: I have got client denied by server configuration: proxy:ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/tomcat error in the error.log

I had to change the Proxy * setting from Deny all to Deny none in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/proxy.conf

Just mentioning here for future lookups.

Comment: This helped me a lot.  I was an idiot and put `http` instead of `ajp`...LOL!

Comment: Please consider modifying your ProxyPassReverse setting, since this seems to be a common mistake according to http://www.humboldt.co.uk/2009/02/the-mystery-of-proxypassreverse.html

Comment: @Jack: Your linked article is useful, but the address is broken. http://www.humboldt.co.uk/the-mystery-of-proxypassreverse/ seems to work.

Comment: Man, you made my day! Your response helped me twice. You're a genius. How did you acquire expertize in this field I may ask?

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve headers like X-FORWARDED-FOR or X-FORWARDED-HOST?

Answer (score 5):

You can read the X-Forwarded-For in the request header.

From the [Apache mod_proxy documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html):

> When acting in a reverse-proxy mode (using the ProxyPass directive, for example), mod_proxy_http adds several request headers in order to pass information to the origin server. These headers are:
>
> - **X-Forwarded-For**: The IP address of the client.
> - **X-Forwarded-Host**: The original host requested by the client in the Host HTTP request header.
> - **X-Forwarded-Server**: The hostname of the proxy server.
>
> Be careful when using these headers on the origin server, since they will contain more than one (comma-separated) value if the original request already contained one of these headers. For example, you can use %{X-Forwarded-For}i in the log format string of the origin server to log the original clients IP address, but you may get more than one address if the request passes through several proxies.

In your servlet, you would have:

```
doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
  request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For")
}
```

Comment: Caution: `X-Forwarded_For` vs `X-Forwarded-For`... Copy-pasting your code can be dangerous :)

Answer (score 1):

this is very simple:

```
<VirtualHost> 

 ServerName www.server.com

 redirect / http://www.server.com/foo

 ProxyRequests off
 ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/

</VirtualHost>
```