# how to use ajax to trigger jenkins job build?

Tags: ajax, jenkins

I'm writing a web page to let others can trigger the some jobs' build with parameters in `jenkins`. So I use ajax to send POST request:

```
var urlString = "http://localhost:8080/job/myjob/buildWithParameters";

$.post(
    urlString,
    {myParam:"there is some data"},
    function(data)
    {
        alert(data);
    },
    "json"
);
```

But I got Http 403 response:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/job/myjob/buildWithParameters. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

I know the cross site problem , but I cannot search any helpful information from Google, can ajax do this job?

UPDATE:
I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154989/login-to-jenkins-using-ajax-javascript)

So I update my code to :

```
$.ajax({                              
    type: "POST",
    url: urlString,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {},
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("admin:123456"));
    },
    success: function(data) {
    },             
    complete: function(xhr, statusText){
    }                                                                 
});
```

I can confirm the username and password is correct , but I got `405 Method Not Allowed`. Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your web page in the userContent folder under $JENKINS_HOME directory. Then open $JENKINS_URL/userContent/yourwebpage.html in your browser. Now the javascript in the page is loaded from the same origin where ajax calls will go, so it should be allowed without CORS tricks.

Comment: For security reasons, Jenkins now prohibits by default the [execution of scripts in the userContent folder](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy#ConfiguringContentSecurityPolicy-RelaxingTheRules).

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins want a POST not a GET HTTP request, a JSONP request is a GET: you can't do that :D

You can try to do in these way:

1. Startup jenkins with the AJP binding as described [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins)
2. Configure Apache2 httpd as a [reverse proxy for the Jenkins AJP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180974/proxypass-proxyreverse-vs-ajp)
3. Force in Apache2 response header as described [here](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html) to enable CORS

At the end you can use directly POST instead of JSONP.

have fun with XSS :D